# iOS Data with Tab Bar Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `tabBarController` which linked with a few `tableViewController`s.

These `tableViewController`s have a custom header section (.xib), so my files are structured like following :

```
MainViewController.h
MainViewController.m

TableHeader.xib
TableHeader.h
TableHeader.m
```

When i load this custom header section in `MainViewController.m`, I send a `NSString` to a function in Table Header.(I send it in the function `viewForHeaderInSection`)

The problem is, when the user shows the first tableview, the second, the third, etc.; and when he comes back on the first tableview per example, the NSString that i sent on my TableHeader is wrong, because my function `viewForHeaderInSection` is not being invoked, and so my TableHeader had the last tableviewcontroller loaded. Of course, i need to have the right NSString in the table header, not the old.

It's hard to describe...I hope it's clear.

thx,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force tableView to reload data you can call:

```
[tableView reloadData]; or [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Add it to viewDidAppeare:animated method and it will force table view to refresh data.
I cannot see the way you get the right NSString, maybe you have to add this logic to viewDidAppeare:animated as well before you reload data.

//Extended

If you have lots of data and you you can reload just one section:

```
[tableView reloadSections: withRowAnimation:];
```

Or you can create custom header view, you can add property/ivar for it and you can reload just the header:

```
[myCustomHederView setNeedsDisplay];
```

Comment: Just don't always reload if the data set is large.

Comment: The problem with that, it's that i reload all of my data just for that :/ (and it takes time to do it)

Comment: Please see extended answer.

Comment: Ok i succeed to do another thing in viewdidappear, and it's running. Thx for the advice :)